# Setting a 1:1 square image to be 10% of the screen height and width css

Tags: css, width

Set the max height to be 10% of the page height.
With a max width to be 10% of the pages width

For example if

Page height is 100px

Page width is 200px

Or

Page height is 200px

Page width is 100px

I would like my image to be set to 10px wide and 10px height

10% of whichever is smaller; the height or width of the page.

I've tried

```
width: 10%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 10%;
```

and

```
max-width: 10%;
max-height: 10%;
```

but they only effected by the width of the page, not the height.

Comment: You won't be able to do that with just CSS, because you'll need to be resizing width based on height (or vice-versa).  You could do it with JavaScript.  Here's an example using jQuery: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zFImG

Answer (score 1):

figured it out

```
width: 10vmin; 
height: 10vmin;
```

CSS 
does 10% of the the smaller of the two, height or width

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units